# Automating email Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a project where if a value in excel is greater than 30000, then an automated email will be sent out. I can't figure out how to loop the macro to run through a column of cells and send the email if it exceeds 30000. This is the code that i put together. I know the if statement needs some major work .

```
Sub outlook_email()


Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Sheets("AC01").Select


StrBody = "On " & Format(Date, "dddd, mmm d yyyy") & " The particle count for a test site is over the Iso 7 Standard of 30,0000 particles for .3 micron particles. " & " Here is the link to the workbook:   




' If statement that determines whether or not to send the email
'The email should only be sent under these conditions: The date is equal to todays date I.E the test was taken and recorded today so its relevant
' If the ISO 7 or 6 standards were surpassed
Cells(ActiveCell.Colum, "O5").Select

If Cells(ActiveCell.Colum, "O5").xl(Down) > 30000 And Cells(ActiveCell.Colum, "C5") = Date Then




' Now we build the email.
    With OutMail
        .To = "me"
        .CC = "me"
        .Subject = "Particle Count Failure"
        .body = StrBody
        .display

    End With
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: So you mean instead of putting in the work yourself you would like us to put in the work?

Comment: Do you know how to loop? Might be easier to understand that first. If you don't, there are tutorials online that should be helpful.